# Blank White Page after Moving CE 1.8.1.0 to a new server

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-gateway, ce-1.8.1.0, amazon-web-services

I just moved a Magento installation from a staging server to the client's Amazon Web Hosting environment. The store functioned without issue on the staging server. The front end behaves correctly in the AWS environment, and I am able to add and delete products without issue. However when I enter the System > Configuration section of the backend and select "Payment Methods," I receive only a blank white page. No other option in the dashboard produces this issue, only "Payment Methods."

The following error stack appears when I cat var/log/exception.log:

```
   Stack trace:
#0 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('relatedslider/p...', Array)
#2 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('relatedslider/p...', 'magentothem_rel...')
#3 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('relatedslider/p...', 'magentothem_rel...')
#4 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'auriga_home')
#9 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'auriga_home')
#10 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/ubuntu/SITEDOMAIN/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Noteworthy is that only the "Payment Methods" tab causes this issue to occur. Ideas on what could have broken during the move?

Comment: remove the cache form the var/www folder and also check the folder permission

Comment: Are you sure this stack trace is relevant to the issue? This seems to be an error on a CMS page originating from the `relatedslider`. Please clear the `exception.log` file and refresh the payment tab again to make sure you only get errors directly tied to that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue specific to the AWS configuration. The mcrypt PHP extension was installed as required by Magento, but not enabled. After enabling the extension in php.ini and restarting Apache, the options in question functioned correctly without the "white screen of death." Thanks all for your comments!